# Character isnt able to move when pressing another button or using mouse, bullet also wont fire

Tags: python, pygame

So I've gotten movement to work for enemy and the player, but when I press a button outside of left or right, like space which will be to shoot, the player cant move and the bullet itself wont actually come out or appear at all. Its in pygame and ima be honest I have no clue whats wrong so im sorry it looks so long and weird

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

background = pygame.image.load("BackgroundImg.jpg")

pygame.display.set_caption("Real Hero")
icon = pygame.image.load('Icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

playerImg = pygame.image.load('Player.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0

enemyImg = pygame.image.load('Enemy.png')
enemyX = random.randint(0, 800)
enemyY = random.randint(50, 150)
enemyX_change = 0.1
enemyY_change = 40

bulletImg = pygame.image.load('Bullet.png')
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 480
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 10
bullet_state = "ready"


def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))


def enemy(x, y):
    screen.blit(enemyImg, (x, y))


def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletImg, (x + 16, y + 10))


running = True
while running:

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            playerX_change = -0.3
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change = 0.3
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            fire_bullet(playerX, bulletY)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0

        playerX += playerX_change
        if playerX <= 0:
            playerX = 0
        elif playerX >= 736:
            playerX = 736

    enemyX += enemyX_change
    if enemyX <= 0:
        enemyX_change = 0.1
        enemyY += enemyY_change
    elif enemyX >= 736:
        enemyX_change = -0.1
        enemyY += enemyY_change

    if bullet_state is "fire":
        fire_bullet(playerX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change

    enemy(enemyX, enemyY)
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html):

```py
running = True
while running:

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # INDENTATION
    #-->|
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -0.3
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0.3
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                fire_bullet(playerX, bulletY)

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    playerX_change = 0
 
    # INDENTATION
    #<--|
    playerX += playerX_change
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736

    enemyX += enemyX_change
    if enemyX <= 0:
        enemyX_change = 0.1
        enemyY += enemyY_change
    elif enemyX >= 736:
        enemyX_change = -0.1
        enemyY += enemyY_change

    if bullet_state is "fire":
        fire_bullet(playerX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change

    enemy(enemyX, enemyY)
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```